# Number agreement with imperative voice and collective noun

Tags: gramática, objetos-directos, imperativo, número-gramatical

In asking my *cuñado* that he "say hello to the family", I said:

> Salúdales a la familia.

I used the plural 3rd-person *-les* with a singular but collective noun (*familia*), because I was referring to my brother-in-law's wife and children.

Is this grammatically correct in Spanish? (Although I'm certain he understood me without any trouble.)

Comment: Did I get that right with my edit?  You were talking to him in Spanish, right?

Comment: @aparente001 yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that is wrong. The pronoun *-les* (which is plural) does not agree with the noun phrase *la familia* (which is singular). Moreover, it is redundant. You can say simply:

> *Saluda a la familia.*

Or more naturally:

> *Dale saludos a la familia.* OR
> *Mándale saludos a la familia.*

There are some cases where you can refer to a collective noun using a plural pronoun, but this happens mostly with nouns like *grupo* or with numerals that work like a collective noun like *millón* when followed by *de* + a plural noun, for example:

> *Un grupo de personas nos esperaban afuera.*
> "A group of people were waiting for us outside."
>
> *Un millón de manifestantes inundaron las calles.*
> "A million protestors flooded the streets."

*Familia* doesn't usually work this way. I've heard people say

> *Toda la familia estábamos muy preocupados.*
> "The whole family *were very worried."

but I don't think that's correct, or if it is, it's not something you as a student of Spanish should learn right now, because it's not standard.

Some people might also say, in your place:

> *Salúdame a la familia.*
> "Say hello to the (=our/your) family for me."

That's called **dative of interest** and it's grammatically correct and rather common in Spanish. A more formal way would be

> *Saluda a la familia de mi parte.*

where *de mi parte* means both "from me" and "on my behalf".

Comment: Great answer and I enjoyed learning the term "dative of interest." (I think that would be a great topic for a canonical Q-A.) // I would add: "Manda saludos a todos," which would be natural if I know the other members of the family well, and "¿Mandas saludos, por favor?" which  is comfortably generic, and thus could work well in a situation where I don't know the other family members, such as in a business setting.

Comment: @aparente001 I'm working on that Q-A.